# ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, carrierwave, nested-forms

I'm trying to create hotel with some fields, one of the fields is photo, i want to use multiple files upload with carrierwave and nested_form. I found this [article](http://lucapette.com/rails/multiple-files-upload-with-carrierwave-and-nested_form/)
and have some result.

When i'm on [/hotels/new](http://img404.imageshack.us/img404/3474/8ta1.png), filling fields, choosing photos 
and press submit, getting **ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError in HotelsController#create unknown attribute: attachable_type.** 
**Console**

```
Started POST "/hotels" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-09-27 17:35:18 +0300
Processing by HotelsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"+1T2tuygSnj8unOKkXkRWI4L7KvDE
9PPHrqvag7KmIQ=", "hotel"=>{"title"=>"dsa", "address"=>"asd", "star_rating"=>"2"
, "breakfast"=>"Not include", "price_for_room"=>"sadas", "room_description"=>"Gr
eat room", "attachments_attributes"=>{"1380289954031"=>{"file"=>#<ActionDispatch
::Http::UploadedFile:0xa5d546c @original_filename="11374.jpg", @content_type="im
age/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"hotel[attachments_at
tributes][1380289954031][file]\"; filename=\"11374.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/
jpeg\r\n", @tempfile=#<File:/tmp/RackMultipart20130927-7077-50zkol>>, "_destroy"
=>"false"}, "1380289972216"=>{"file"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0xa5d
53a4 @original_filename="357175.jpg", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Cont
ent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"hotel[attachments_attributes][1380289972216][
file]\"; filename=\"357175.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n", @tempfile=#<F
ile:/tmp/RackMultipart20130927-7077-dlkmwk>>, "_destroy"=>"false"}}}, "commit"=>
"Done"}
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 109ms

ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError (unknown attribute: attachable_type):
  app/controllers/hotels_controller.rb:15:in `new'
  app/controllers/hotels_controller.rb:15:in `create' 
...
```

**Model hotel.rb**

```
class Hotel < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :address, :breakfast, :price_for_room, :room_description,
                :star_rating, :title, :attachments_attributes

  has_many :attachments, :as => :attachable
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :attachments
end
```

**Model attachment.rb**

```
class Attachment < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :file  
  belongs_to :attachable, :polymorphic => true
  mount_uploader :file, FileUploader
end
```

**hotels_controller.rb**

```
...
      def new
        @hotel = Hotel.new
      end
      def create
        @hotel = Hotel.new(params[:hotel])
        if @hotel.save
          redirect_to hotels_path, notice: "Nice, you added new hotel " + @hotel.title
        else
          render "new"
        end  
      end
```

**_form.rb**

```
<%= nested_form_for @hotel, :html => {:multipart => true}  do |f| %>
  ...
  <%= f.fields_for :attachments do |attachment_form|%>    
    <%= attachment_form.label :file %>
    <%= attachment_form.file_field :file %>
    <%= attachment_form.link_to_remove "Remove this photo" %>
  <% end %>
  <%= f.link_to_add "Add photo", :attachments %>
  <%= f.submit 'Done', class: 'btn btn-success' %>
<% end %>
```

Any ideas guys? What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 8):

ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError means that you're missing a field in the database. Looks like you missed a field when you were setting up your polymorphic relationship, or you forgot to run your migrations.

See also: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations

Comment: forgot to run migrations post pull

Answer (score 0):

try to create a file names 
**app/uploaders/photo_uploader.rb**

```
# encoding: utf-8
class PhotoUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  # Include RMagick or MiniMagick support:
  include CarrierWave::RMagick
  # include CarrierWave::MiniMagick
  include Sprockets::Helpers::RailsHelper
  include Sprockets::Helpers::IsolatedHelper
  include CarrierWave::MimeTypes
  process :set_content_type
  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end
  def extension_white_list
     %w(jpg jpeg gif png)
  end
# process :resize_to_fit => [800, 800]

  version :thumb do
    process :resize_to_limit => [50, 50]
  end
end
```

then in your model add

```
mount_uploader :image, PhotoUploader
mount_uploader :image2, PhotoUploader
```

you probably have this

**/config/initializers/carrierwave.rb**

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
  config.storage = :fog
  config.fog_credentials = {
    :provider => 'AWS',
    :aws_access_key_id => ENV['CARRIER_WAVE_ACCESS_KEY'],
    :aws_secret_access_key => ENV['CARRIER_WAVE_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']
  }
  config.cache_dir = "#{Rails.root}/tmp/uploads"
  config.fog_directory = ENV['CARRIER_WAVE_BUCKET']
  config.fog_attributes = { 'Cache-Control'=>'max-age=315576000' }
  #config.fog_public = false # optional, defaults to true
end
```

Comment: /config/initializers/carrierwave.rb it conects to the AWS to store the files, you can replace `ENV['CARRIER_WAVE_ACCESS_KEY']` with your values to connect