# ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError - a missing attribute in a User model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I am new to Ruby on Rails, and I am coming across an UnknownAttributeError through my rspec tests. Where and how do you debug this issue? Thanks in advance.

I've looked through these questions, but my problem is NOT -

- polymorphic [ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19053734/activerecordunknownattributeerror)
- heroku - I'm not using kerokuapp [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8139578/activerecordunknownattributeerror](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19053734/activerecordunknownattributeerror)

  Failures:

  1) SessionsController post create logs you in with the correct password
       Failure/Error: let(:connie) {User.create(name: 'Connie', password: 'M4heswaran')}
       ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError:
         unknown attribute 'name' for User.

I am creating a login page with name, password, and password confirmation, along with a submit button by using form_for.

```
<h1>Welcome!</h1>
<h3>Please log in, stranger.</h3>
<%= form_for @user do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :name %>
  <%= f.text_field :name %>

  <%= f.label :password %>
  <%= f.text_field :password %>

  <%= f.label :password_confirmation %>
  <%= f.text_field :password_confirmation %>

  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

I also have a Sessions controller with actions that allows a session to be created when a user logs in:

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  def new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.find_by(name: params[:user][:name])
  end
end
```

Here is my users controller, just in case, so that I'm not leaving anything out

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def new
  end

  def create
    user = User.new(user_params).save
  end

  private

  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:name, :password, :password_confirmation)
  end
end
```

"name" is an attribute in my users table. Here is my schema below:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20170416184846) do

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "password_digest"
    t.datetime "created_at",      null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",      null: false
  end
end
```

And I only have a ActionController class method `before_action` which shouldn't affect the unknown attribute error.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_secure_password
end
```

I also created a record in `rails c`, and I successfully saved one.

```
2.3.0 :002 > User.create(name: "Dave", password: "dave", password_confirmation: "dave")
```

(0.1ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (0.5ms)  INSERT INTO "users" ("name", "password_digest", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)  [["name", "Dave"], ["password_digest", "$2a$10$bq9G.od4ecoTRWg0dlwREudjdDX5QFa7L.c1U2Jd6qoKmCnGNG61O"], ["created_at", "2017-04-16 20:41:04.061507"], ["updated_at", "2017-04-16 20:41:04.061507"]]
   (0.8ms)  commit transaction
 => #

And finally, here are my routes:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get '/login', to: 'sessions#new'
  post '/login', to: 'sessions#create'
  delete '/logout', to: 'sessions#destroy'
end
```

Here is the rspec file for SessionsController:

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe SessionsController, type: :controller do

  before do
    User.destroy_all
  end

  let(:connie) {User.create(name: 'Connie', password: 'M4heswaran')}

  describe 'post create' do
    it 'logs you in with the correct password' do
      post :create, user: {name: connie.name, password: connie.password}
      expect(session[:user_id]).to eq(connie.id)
    end

    it 'rejects invalid passwords' do
      post :create, user: {name: connie.name, password: connie.password + 'x'}
      expect(session[:user_id]).to be_nil
    end

    it 'rejects empty passwords' do
      post :create, user: {name: connie.name, password: ''}
      expect(session[:user_id]).to be_nil
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Where do you see that message @Iceman?

Comment: Could you add the entire sessions_controller_spec?

Comment: Sure, I just updated the question with spec file for SessionsController @Anton

Comment: Do puts connie at the top of your test and check out the log. Is there a valid object? Why don't you do user: connie instead of the hash?

Comment: I got "connie", and my tests ran the same afterwards. I actually ran `bin/rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=development`, and that helped clear the unknown attribute error! Thanks @Iceman @Anton

Comment: @Iceman I'd encourage you to put your answer up so that user112514 can accept your answer as the correct one. It might be useful to direct her to the appropriate point in the rails guides

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to set up your test database also with this command from the terminal

```
rails db:test:prepare
```

One other way would be

```
RAILS_ENV=test rails db:migrate
```

Can read more about this all in the [excellent guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#the-test-database)

Answer (score 0):

If you have just started and no data in your database start from fresh

Drop the database:

```
rake db:drop
```

Create all database:

```
rake db:create
```

prepare your test db:

```
rake db:test:prepare
```

migrate your db:

```
rake db:migrate
```

then migrate your db for test env:

```
rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=test
```